# How to prevent Highstock from hiding data rows

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highstock chart with type `scatter`. When I use the range selector some of the series disappear cause the have no data in the current range. How can I prevent the chart from scaling to only the existing data an keep the yaxis in the initial state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see only two options:

- set fixed min and max for yAxis
- in `afterSetExtremes` call `yAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max)` in setTimeout function, but you need to calculate min and max on your own.