# Combine two arrays in js or have highcharts working with other data format

Tags: json, sqlite, highcharts

I have a sqlite database with such tables:
1. time
2. cpu
3. mem
4. ...

I want to put all these values on Highstock Chart where time will be my xAsis. I have a cgi script which is returning data in format 
[ [time1, time2, time3], [cpu1, cpu2, ...], [mem1, mem2...] ]

As far as I know Highcharts wants the data to be like [ [time1, cpu1], [time2, cpu2] ] for each series. Is there any way to combine values from my format to this format? Something like matrix = [time[], cpu[]]

I tried rewriting them in loop, but it was poor idea with big amount of data. (Such loops are impossible in this case (performance issues) because chart will be updated every 1-2 seconds due to new points in database AND have lazy loading - as described: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130735/highstock-how-to-combine-lazy-loading-and-dynamic-data) ).

I'm little sceptical about sending data in format [ [time1, cpu1], [time2, cpu2] ] because IMO it will be very heavy. If im wrong, please correct me. And for now I don't really know how to do it.

my cgi script for sqlite->json:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Content-type: text/plain
echo

#sqlite3 to json
#playing with field separators to get params working
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS="${IFS}&"
set $QUERY_STRING
Args="$*"
IFS="$OIFS"


# params:
# 1 - start (int)
# 2 - end (int)
TIMESTART="$1"
shift
TIMEEND="$1"

if [[ $TIMESTART =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && [[ $TIMEEND =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo "["
    echo -en "[";  sqlite3 /home/moonitor/moonitor-misc/data/cpu.db "select time from usage_cpu where time between '$TIMESTART' and '$TIMEEND' " | tr '|' ',' | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/, /g' ; echo "],"
    echo -en "[";  sqlite3 /home/moonitor/moonitor-misc/data/cpu.db "select time, summary from usage_cpu where time between '$TIMESTART' and '$TIMEEND'" | tr '|' ',' | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/, /g' ; echo "],"
    echo -en "[";  sqlite3 /home/moonitor/moonitor-miscd/ata/cpu.db "select time, user from usage_cpu where time between '$TIMESTART' and '$TIMEEND'" | tr '|' ',' | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/, /g' ; echo "],"
    echo -en "[";  sqlite3 /home/moonitor/moonitor-misc/data/cpu.db "select time, nice from usage_cpu where time between '$TIMESTART' and '$TIMEEND'" | tr '|' ',' | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/, /g' ; echo "],"
    echo -en "[";  sqlite3 /home/moonitor/moonitor-misc/data/cpu.db "select time, kernel from usage_cpu where time between '$TIMESTART' and '$TIMEEND'" | tr '|' ',' | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/, /g' ; echo "]"
    echo "]"
fi
```

Comment: Are you time points "regular" (the same between series and the same difference between each point)?  Are you sending **all** the data on each update or only the new points?

Comment: What I wrote above is little simplified. The script is reading cpu usage (kernel/user/nice/total) and time in linux epoch. **So the time is always the same for 4 points (series)**. Distances between measures are typically 1 second but sometimes script is off so there will be for exapmle 1 week without any point. But there will be no situation when i have some value (eg. kernel usage) missing - all or none.
I want to send single [time, point, point, point, poinn] every second, but i'll probably have to send **all** data when user will scroll the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, in terms of communication between user<->server, it's better to attach only once  timestamp. And still you can do it, then just convert your data format to fit Highcharts requirements, simple snippet:

```
function convertData(data) {
  var s = [{
    name: 'cpu',
    data: []
  },{
    name: 'nice',
    data: []
  },{
    name: 'test',
    data: []
  }]; //create series array for chart


  // append points
  $.each(data, function(i, vals) {
    s[0].data.push([ vals[0], vals[1] ]);
    s[1].data.push([ vals[0], vals[2] ]);
    s[2].data.push([ vals[0], vals[3] ]);        
  });

  return s;
}
```

And live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ywr3L/43/

**Note:** I'm using fixed number of points (three series). If you don't know how many of them is available it will be better to create series inside another loop.